# Httplib2 invalid syntax error with [python3.6]

Tags: python, python-3.x, httplib, httplib2

I build app with python3 long time ago.
And these days unfortunately I've broken my pc and something happened to my ubuntu server and no longer use so I reconfigured it and cloned my python app from my github repo and deployed by same step before except some dependency's updating.
Then I got error message.
I know this is a compatibility issue about python 2 and 3. But how can I fix this?

```
[Thu Mar 07 16:07:12.139598 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10828:tid 139884947846912] [remote 99.230.56.77:63637]   File "/var/www/ItemCatalogApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 462
[Thu Mar 07 16:07:12.139604 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10828:tid 139884947846912] [remote 99.230.56.77:63637]     print("%s:" % h, end=" ", file=self._fp)
[Thu Mar 07 16:07:12.139608 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10828:tid 139884947846912] [remote 99.230.56.77:63637]                         ^
[Thu Mar 07 16:07:12.139612 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 10828:tid 139884947846912] [remote 99.230.56.77:63637] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are somehow using Python 3.x modules from a Python 2.x installation.  Install 3.x (if you don't have it installed already), and explicitly run your program with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are running this code in Python 2, not Python 3.

`end=` and `file=` are not valid in Python 2 unless you have `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your program.